# groovy: 139: unable to resolve class XmlParser

Tags: jenkins, groovy

When trying to run the groovy script from Jenkins getting the below error

```
C:\Jenkins\workspace\Load-Test-for-container-HimaM13\hudson16255048887172875424.groovy: 139: unable to resolve class XmlParser @ line 139, column 14.
            def root = new XmlParser().parseText(response)
            ^
```

Groovy version used **groovy-4.0.0-rc-2**

Code snippet

```
try {
        String response = sendSoap(request, "getSamlArtifact")
        def soapNS = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "SOAP")
        def samlProtocolNS = new groovy.xml.Namespace("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol", "samlp")
        def root = new XmlParser().parseText(response)
        def assertionArtifact = root[soapNS.Body][samlProtocolNS.Response][samlProtocolNS.AssertionArtifact]

        if (null == assertionArtifact[0]){
            //printString("value1-"+assertionArtifact[0])
            return null
        }
        else
            return assertionArtifact[0].text();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it worked after trying with

```
 def root = new groovy.xml.XmlParser().parseText(response)
```

instead of

```
 def root = new XmlParser().parseText(response)
```

Comment: yeah, you could also add an `import groovy.xml.XmlParser`